# 419 - Session Expired without event authentication after deployment | Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, session-cookies

My Laravel application works fine in on my local machine and on my staging server. But when I deployed to my production server the login form is not working. Every time I try to login to the admin panel it shows my

> 419
>
> Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.

My Head Tag contains `<meta name="csrf-token" content="XXX">`

My login form contains `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="XXX">`

**What have I tried so far:**

- Tried generating new key `php artisan key:generate`
- Tried clearing all caches
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan route:clear`
- `php artisan view:clear`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- Checked php.ini max_execution_time and memory limits.
- Tried changing `SESSION_DRIVER` from **file** to **database**

**The only thing that kind of worked but was unsafe and was for debugging purpose**

In the *VerifyCsrfToken* class, I added  "api/login" & "api/register" in `protected $except` and the form worked. Like this

```
namespace FleetCart\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        "api/login",
        "api/register"
    ];
}
```

Please help me understand how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after spending 3 days I found the solution.

@Snapey helped me fixing this issue.

You can see the answer here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/419-session-expired-without-event-authentication-after-deployment-laravel-57

In my case, there was an extra space before starting `<?php` tag.